# tomcat a service with the given service name is already installed

Tags: windows, tomcat8

I have to uninstall tomcat before reinstall it.But, I mistakenly deleted the file folder first and then uninstalled it from "control Panel", during this process I think somewhat might be got wrong. Now when I am trying to install it it is giving me the message:-

[image]

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 10):

it means that you have already installed a version of tomcat8 on your pc. But you can fix this problem by opening the cmd in administrator mode. then you start the command:

```
sc.exe delete tomcat8
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because the server is not fully out of your computer, here follow these steps to remove the existing server on windows:

1. Navigate to Control Panel.
2. Open Administrative tools.
3. Open SERVICES.
4. You will find Apache tomcat version name, right click on it and open properties.
5. Cope the name of the server: Tomcat8/Tomcat9.
6. Now open and run the command prompt as an administrator: 
   https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-run-command-prompt-as-an-administrator
7. Write the command: sc Delete Tomcat8/Tomcat9 and hit enter, the existing server is 
   removed and you are all set to install a new one.